# Arithmetical Progression Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given arithmetic progression where  $${S}_{2n} = 2013$$ and $${S}_{3n} = 2001$$. Question $${S}_{n}=?$$
Please give me hint to solve this problem.

Comment: What does the notation of Sn stand for? The sum or the terms of the AP?

Answer (score 1):

Letting $a = S_0$ and $d  = S_1 - S_0$, we have
$$S_n + S_{3n} = a + nd + a + (3n)d = 2(a + (2n)d) = 2S_{2n}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$S_m=\dfrac m2\{2a+(m-1)d\}$$ where $a,d$ be the first term, common difference respectively.

Put $m=2n,3n$ to solve for $a,d$ in terms of $n$

Answer (score 0):

If $S_n$  stands for the sum of Arithmetic Progression, then things get a little bit harder.

Because [the derivation of the sum of AP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Derivation), $S_n$ can be written as this form: $an^2+bn$, where a and b are arbitary constant.

The goal is $S_n$ (i.e. $an^2+bn$). Here $a$ and $b$ are fixed because of the AP is a fixed sequence.

Because ${S}_{2n} = 2013,{S}_{3n} = 2001$, the following equation systems are hold.

$4an^2+2bn =2013$

$ 9an^2+3bn=2001$

solve for unknown factor $an^2$ and $bn$ => $an^2 = -679/2$ and  $bn = 3371/2$

Therefore $S_n$ = $1346$

But if $S_n$ stands for the terms in AP, thing becomes trivial and easier.

$S_{3n} - S_{2n} = S_{2n} - S_{n} = d$ where d is the common difference of AP,

=>

$ S_{n} = S_{2n} - d = S_{2n}-(S_{3n}-S_{2n}) = 2013-(2001-2013) = 2025$